# Freeze particle effect in Sprite Kit iOS

Tags: sprite, sprite-kit, freeze, particles

Is there a way to freeze a particle node in Sprite Kit for iOS? Basically freeze each of the particles in the particle node exactly where they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pause the particle node:

```
particle.paused = YES;
```

Comment: NICE! Thank you!!! I saw that property but for some reason didn't think it would do that. I thought it would stop the emission or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
particle.paused = YES;
```

This is also useful in order to speed up performance when an emitter is offscreen and doesn't need to be emitting particles.